# Deserialize a Json containing a list of object

Tags: c#, json, web-services, serialization, json.net

I work on an UniversalApp that call a lot of webservices returning JSON datas.

All the webservices return me a first level of Json (**WsResponse.cs**), that contained this structure:

```
public string status { get; set; }
public object data { get; set; }
public List<object> errors { get; set; }
```

If the status is "**success**", I can deserialize the simple data object by:

```
WsResponse wsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WsResponse>(response);    
User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(wsResponse.data.ToString());
```

In other cases, it is necessary to deserialize first in a result object, before to deserialize the datas:

```
WsResponse wsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WsResponse>(response);
WsResponseResult wsResponseResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WsResponseResult>(
                                                            wsResponse.data.ToString());
List<Theme> themes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Theme>>(
                                                    wsResponseResult.result.ToString());
```

But if the status is "**failure**", I need to catch the errors list. But I can't deserialize this object list...
Here is an example of JSON datas that I get from webservice when it contains errors:

```
{
  "status": "failure",
  "data": {},
  "errors": [
    {
      "200": "The parameter 'email' is not present"
    },
    {
      "200": "The parameter 'password' is not present"
    }
  ]
}
```

I try to deserialize it by:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvpError = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
kvpError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<<string, string>>>(
                                                            wsResponse.errors.ToString());

Dictionary<string, string> dError = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(
                                                            wsResponse.errors.ToString());
```

**=> but it doesn't work**

I also try to through the error datas before deserializing them:

```
foreach(var error in wsResponse.errors)
{                        
    KeyValuePair<string, string> kvpError = new KeyValuePair<string,string>();
    kvpError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(
                                                                        error.ToString());
}
```

**=> but it doesn't work better...**

***Would you have an idea on how to solve my problem?***

Answer (score 1):

The way your JSON is structured, `errors` is actually a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`. If you use that instead of `List<object>`, it will deserialize the errors properly:

```
public class Response
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> errors { get; set; }
}
```

Yields:

[image: Deserialization result]

Side note - If you have any control of the JSON structure, you're better off with a single `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` which you can deserialize. Also, instead of using `object data`, actually pass the `User` properties inside the JSON so you can save yourself the double deserialization.

If you wanted to make it possible to deserialize this to a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, your JSON would need to look like this:

```
{
  "status": "failure",
  "data": {},
  "errors": [
    {
      "Key": "200", "Value": "The parameter 'email' is not present"
    },
    {
      "Key": "200", "Value": "The parameter 'password' is not present"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine.
But this structure of the JSON is not very good, because each dictionnary will contain only one item...

Comment: @Gold.strike - I agree, that's what I've said in the buttom pqrt of my answer. Consider refactoring your JSON if possible.

Comment: I will talk to the issue with my client, to see if we can change the JSON structure.
Which tool have you used to find the type of the object?

Comment: @Gold.strike I didn't use a tool, I simply have experience with JSON and serialization, so I knew that was the issue.